# Expo app stuck on splash screen in –no-dev –minify, however, it works fine running expo start

Tags: react-native, mobile, expo, splash-screen

My app works fine in local development simulator running just the expo start command, however, when I uploaded it to testflight and test it in the iphone the app was stuck on the splash screen. So I tried to replicate the process in simulator by running expo start --no-dev --minify, however, the app still stucks on the splash screen. Whereas when I run expo start the app works fine. I’ve been stuck on this bug for a couple of days, any help would be deeply appreciated. Below I’ve attached my package.js and system logs error.

Failed to bootstrap path: path = /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/dyld_sim, error = 2: No such file or directory[image]

Comment: hey @S.C any chance that you've found a solution to this?